# How to create a dynamic navigation menu?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, menu, navigation

How to create a dynamic navigation menu (PHP variable based) that can populate the dynamic links based on the corresponding values of users' ID reserved in Mysql database during a session?

Comment: I've resolved the problem by echoing / querying the session variable as the value of primary key inside the herf tag. The following tags demonstrate how have I done that.


<a href="user.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>">User Account</a>
<a href="user.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>">User Setting</a>
<a href="user.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>">User Profile</a>

Answer (score -2):

I've resolved the problem finally. I'm posting the solution here so that it may become a guideline to the other viewers.

It can be done by echoing / querying the predefined PHP variavles like form variable & session variable, etc. as the value of primary or unique key (Here 'id' is both a primary key and a unique key by default) inside the herf tag.

```
<a href="user.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>">User Account</a>
<a href="user.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>">User Setting</a>
<a href="user.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>">User Profile</a>
```

Thanks,

Comment: It seems a bit strange to place a session variable in a querystring. The user.php script probably has access to the session as well.

Comment: Why it's strange to place a session variable in a query string? Would you explain? The way I resolved the problem is serving my purpose perfectly. What is your idea to populate the links of a navigation menu dynamically based on the corresponding values of users' ID reserved in Mysql database during a session like log in session? Yes, the user.php script has access to the session only after the users log in to their accounts successfully.